# How to estimate cluster homoscedastic model?

Tags: regression, heteroscedasticity

This is a follow-up to "[How to estimate variance for identical & fraternal twins with a mixed model](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/322509/how-to-estimate-variance-for-identical-fraternal-twins-with-a-mixed-model)" for more clarification of my understanding.

I believe there are some theoretical analogues to common tests of mediation, causality, and heritability if (what I call) a "cluster homoscedastic" type of model can be estimated.

Specifically, I am interested in estimating the following type of linear model:

$$Y_i  = \beta_0 + \beta_1 X_{i,1} + \ldots \beta_p X_{i,p} + \epsilon_i$$

Where $\epsilon_i \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2_j)$ (independent but not identical) for $i \in C_j$, $j < n$. Where $C_j$ is a cluster indicator of observations sharing a common variance. $C_j$ is known but $\sigma^2_j$ is not.

Are there any known methods to estimate this type of model and the variance components?

Answer (score 0):

One easy way to do this is just maximum likelihood.

Define the negative log-likelihood function in R with:

```
nloglik <- function(b) {
  yhat <- x * b[1] + b[2]
  resid <- y - yhat
  rsd <- tapply(resid, group, sd)[match(group, sort(unique(group)))]
  -sum(dnorm(resid, 0, rsd, log=T) )
}
```

and solve using the quasi-Newton algorithm `nlm`. As an example:

```
## misspecify model: quadratic trend fit linearly: 
## 0 trend in homoscedastic model
## greater variance for positive X, neg trend
## CH-model should show more neg trend

set.seed(123)
x <- seq(-3, 3, 0.1)
group <- ifelse(x > 0, 3, 1)
y <- rnorm(length(x), x^2, e) 

res <- nlm(nloglik, p=c(0, mean(y)), hessian=T)
```

Gives:

```
> res$estimate
[1]  3.25556481 -0.07235687
> lm(y~ x)

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)            x  
    3.34464      0.09962
```